# How can I repair fiberglass wallpaper with holes in it?

Tags: repair, walls, painting, wallpaper, fiberglass

I just bought a house that has fiberglass wallpaper in a couple of rooms.

In one of the rooms the wallpaper was not properly applied and it's full of little holes. From what I read it means not enough glue was applied when putting the wallpaper up.

[image: overview]

[image: detail]

Does anyone know if there is a way to fix or minimize the problem without having to redo the work?

Comment: Is it possible that the wallpaper has been painted and those are areas where the paint did not adhere or flaked away?

Comment: Hi. It's fiberglass wallpaper, it's not a normal wallpaper. It's supposed to be painted. It's not about paint not adhering, it's really holes due to not enough glue being added while putting the fiberglass.
I can paint it again and the holes will still be there because the paint will go behind the fiberglass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it looking good by filling the holes with paint and passing the brush over it a couple of times after it was painted, while drying. The fiberglass glued to the wall.

Hope it helps someone!